# Principal component analysis m-by-n matrix implementation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, normalization, pca

Does anyone know how to implement the Principal component analysis (PCA) on a m-by-n matrix in matlab for normalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each column is a sample (that is, you have `n` samples each of dimension `m`), and it's stored in a matrix `A` you first have to subtract off the column means:

```
      Amm = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A,2));
```

then you want to do an eigenvalue decomposition on `1/size(Amm,2)*Amm*Amm'` (you can use `1/(size(Amm,2)-1)` as a scale factor if you want an interpetation as an unbiased covariance matrix) with:

```
      [v,d] = eig(1/size(Amm,2)*Amm*Amm');
```

And the columns of `v` are going to be your PCA vectors.  The entries of `d` are going to be your corresponding "variances".

However, if your `m` is huge then this is not the best way to go because storing `Amm*Amm'` is not practical.  You want to instead compute:

```
      [u,s,v] = svd(1/sqrt(size(Amm,2))*Amm,'econ');
```

This time `u` contains your PCA vectors.  The entries of `s` are related to the entries of `d` by a `sqrt`.

Note: there's another way to go if `m` is huge, i.e. computing `eig(1/size(Amm,2)*Amm
'*Amm);` (notice the switch of transposes as compared to above) and doing a little trickery, but it's a longer explanation so I won't get into it.

Comment: Brilliant break down and explanations +1!